# embedding a youtube video in Responsive Grid System framework (video doesn't load)

Tags: html, video, youtube, responsive-design, grid

so I'm programming an assessed site for my degree and I've come to one of the few elements which need fixing. This is getting the YouTube embedding video to load. Now I have got it down to only one broken video.

This has been used on the http://www.responsivegridsystem.com/ which has been approved by my course lecturer. To give a quick idea, I want the first video to be placed to the right with the description on the left, the second one video to be placed to the let and the description on the right, and the third video to be just like the first.

the code below:

```
<!--content-->

    <div id="maincontentcontainer">
        <div class="standardcontainer" id="example">
            <div class="maincontent">


                <div class="section group">
                    <div class="col span_1_of_3">
                    <h3>Sesame Street: Do De Duckie With Ernie</h3>
                    <p></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col span_2_of_3">
<iframe width="480" height="360" src="http://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/W6_d22aMqZs?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen </iframe>
                    </div>
                </div>       

<!--next video-->

                <div class="section group">
                    <div class="col span_2_of_3">
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/gRfPqV6L2MA?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen </iframe>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col span_1_of_3">
                    <h3>Is It A Good Idea To Microwave Rubber Ducks?</h3>
                    <p></p>
                    </div>
                </div>

<!--next video-->

                <div class="section group">
                    <div class="col span_1_of_3">
                    <h3>Dany T - Rubber Ducky (Official Teaser)</h3>
                    <p></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col span_2_of_3">
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/TDLxEWelXsE?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen </iframe>
                    </div>
                </div>  
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

WHAT actually happens when I trial the page out in Chrome (my main testing browser), only the first and third video are loaded while the second video is non existent.

ANY HELP???

Answer (score 0):

you're not closing your `iframe`s correctly:

this:

```
<iframe width="480" height="360" src="http://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/W6_d22aMqZs?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen </iframe>
```

should be this:

```
<iframe width="480" height="360" src="http://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/W6_d22aMqZs?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

To demonstrate without all of the other code, yours is:

```
<iframe </iframe>
```

instead of

```
<iframe></iframe>
```

All three of them are like that

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/4ndw67x1/)

Comment: THATS WHAT IT WAS ;D... Thanks bro, it was just bugging me.. I don't get it though because that's the code copied from the YouTube embedded site... Either way, thank you!!

Comment: @Intramista you got it. Glad to help. Can you check this off as resolved?